# Drag and drop image from pop up window back to activity

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Drag and Drop functionality in my application. In app, there is one activity. On the click of button one window pops up. This window has images displayed in grid view. Now I want to drag and drop one of the images back to to the activity. 
Is it possible to this? Any idea or link would be helpful that I can use to learn about this thing.

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/

Comment: Deveoper Link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: @GopiKrishna  I have tried that javacodegeeks example.It does not work in this case..